# Picking in non gl draw

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I've developed infrastructure for both canvas2d and webgl drawing methods.

I've developed picking method for webgl and the goal is also to do so to canvas2d. have problem with the anti aliasing of canvas 2d.

In webgl it was easy, simply in the shader changing the colors, removing some alpha values and the job was done.

But in cavnas2d i don't have this power, and tried many technics to avoid that, but sadly didn't manage. The problem occurs in the edges of the text. There the values of the pixel are different than the picking color.. If it was only the alpha it was not a problem. but the rgb itself is different.

So I Ignore the pixel when alpha is not 255 (No i have problem in small texts which most of the pixels are with alpha due to anti aliasing.

Another problem is when one text is over another then the edges blends and there is not alpha (a=255).

[image: Regular zoom]

[image: red rectangle zoom]

Didn't find anyway to disable the anti-aliasing.. and tried some `context.globalCompositeOperation` values with no luck.

Anyone with suggestions ?

Comment: You can not disable the text anti-aliasing on the 2D canvas. Nor is there a reliable method to know original pixel values after a render call as there is a significant loss of information in the rendering operation. You can render text to a separate canvas, or keep a copy of the canvas before each new render call but that can be memory expensive. Though if the images are simple you can store the canvas as PNG's to reduce the memory overhead, also only keeping changed pixels will reduce this even further. Your best bet is to log render calls such that you can de/re construct the image from them

Comment: I am drawing to separate canvas. In the picture above i just drew it to the main to show my problem. My picking is performed on mouse down. so it can take 300ms max (which is allot). But didn't quite get your answer about storing changed pixels and de/re construct the image ? My frame can be thousands of texts & images in different colors. My picking will be single color for each object (which can hold texts and/or images)

Comment: If you record the render calls then you can pick via pixel test first and then find the best option from the list of render calls. eg `ctx.fillText("A",10,10); ctx.fillText("B",20,20);` and the mouse picks a black pixel near 25,25 then it is likely the "B" Then to remove rerender all apart from "B" This method can quickly find the desired text though thousands or items, but reconstructing the canva can take time, or deleting (deconstruction) text if not overlapping will be quick.